# Boss is overloading me with work because I want to resign

Tags: conflict, conflict-resolution

I started as an intern at a family-owned company. After a year working for them, my supervisor's brother and I started dating.

My boyfriend, his brother and their parents all live in the same house.

Lately, I have been feeling unmotivated at work and would like to find another job. My current job pays less than half the market salary (I do not have a contract), which prevents me from helping my financially-troubled parents as much as I wish. In addition, my supervisor is not consistent and can be pretty mean.

He recently found out about my plans to resign and all a sudden he is trying to get me to do more than I can manage. He added an additional project to my workload and is trying to make sure all the knowledge I have acquired is documented.

I originally wanted to leave at the end of the year, but due to the increased stress, I'm am considering leaving much sooner.

How do I maintain the situation until year-end? I'm not sure if stick it out that long.

Comment: Welcome to the Workplace -- thanks for your question. Some of the information seems to be missing. Can you edit to correct and clarify? Also, it's hard to answer broad questions like "How do I maintain the situation till year end" -- can you focus more narrowly on what you'd like to know?

Comment: The dating relationship should be irrelevant.

Comment: The living in the same household as the supervisor may be relevant, though it's not clear from the post.

Comment: You may want to be careful posting under your own name. You can now google _yourname_ + resign and this posting appears.

Answer (score 6):

Tell the boss that you'd be glad to work on any of these things for the remainder of the year but that if you try to do all of them at once that risks none being done to his satisfaction -- or to yours. Ask him to set clear priorities, remembering that he isn't paying overtime.

With priorities, work your way through it as best you can. If there isn't time to complete something despite your best efforts, there isn't, and that's all there is to it.

If management sets all priorities equal, they can't (or shouldn't) fault you for making your own decisions.